# Rspec: Getting error while testing private method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

Getting error while testing a private method. Please suggest how to test private method is called from a public method.

Public

```
def public_method
    private_method
end
```

Private

```
  def private_method
    tries = 0
    begin
      raise Product::StaleObjectError.new("Product is changed while you were editing") if stale_object?
      // Do some work
      raise Exception.new("Total amount used is greater than approved") if total_approved < 0

      // Save Product
    rescue Product::StaleObjectError => e
      if tries < MAX_RETRIES
        tries += 1
        sleep(1 + tries)
        reload
        retry
      else
        raise Product::StaleObjectError("Product is changed while you were editing")
      end
    end
    attributes
  end
```

Test Case:

```
  before(:each) do
    @prod_v1 = Product.new
  end
  it 'test private method called' do
    expect_any_instance_of {Product}.to receive(:private_method)
    @prod_v1.public_method
  end
```

I am getting following error for test case

```
  Failure/Error: expect_any_instance_of {Product}.to receive(:)
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Comment: @SimpleLime  The original code is different from the here. It was a typo Code. Updated question.

Comment: Why are you using curly braces?, try with Product within parenthesis.

Comment: @SebastianPalma working. thanks a lot. Can you update your Answer? So that I can accept.

Comment: Sure, can you tell me what version of RSpec, rspec-rails are you using?

Comment: `Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.22.4)
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.3"`

Comment: @SebastianPalma Can you suggest how should I use  exactly(3).times `expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:private_method).exactly(3).times. For it I am getting error:    Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
       (Project 1 (0001)).private_method(any args)
           expected: 3 times with any arguments
           received: 1 time with any arguments`

Comment: it should work as is now. You could create a new question adding the proper info for recreating your issue.

Comment: @SebastianPalma Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52691340/rspec-how-to-test-an-exception-is-raised-in-private-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [expect_any_instance_of](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance), this will receive the class as a method argument, so you should use parenthesis instead of curly braces:

```
it 'test private method called' do
  expect_any_instance_of(Product).to receive(:private_method)
  ...
end
```